# Save images in XAMPP server from Cordova with PHP

Tags: php, cordova

My requirement is to save the images taken from Camera of Cordova plugin and save the image in a server . I have used below code and achieved getting the image , but how do i save in a server using PHP

```
// Code to capture photo from camera and show gps co ordinates 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Capture Photo</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

var pictureSource;   // picture source
var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value
// Wait for device API libraries to load
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
// device APIs are available
function onDeviceReady() {
pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}
// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
// Uncomment to view the base64-encoded image data
// console.log(imageData);
// Get image handle
//
var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');
// Unhide image elements
//
smallImage.style.display = 'block';
// Show the captured photo
// The in-line CSS rules are used to resize the image
//
 smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
 }
 // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
 //
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
// Uncomment to view the image file URI
// console.log(imageURI);
 // Get image handle
 //
var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');
// Unhide image elements
 //
 largeImage.style.display = 'block';
 // Show the captured photo
 // The in-line CSS rules are used to resize the image
 //
 largeImage.src = imageURI;
 }
// A button will call this function
//
function capturePhoto() {
// Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded   string
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
}
// A button will call this function
//
function capturePhotoEdit() {
// Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image as     base64-encoded string
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20,      allowEdit: true,
destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
}
// A button will call this function
//
function getPhoto(source) {
// Retrieve image file location from specified source
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
sourceType: source });
}
// Called if something bad happens.
//
function onFail(message) {
alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
 // button to capture photo  
<button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button> <br>
// button to capture editable photo
<button onclick="capturePhotoEdit();">Capture Editable Photo</button> <br>
//button to select images from library
<button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo  Library</button><br>
<button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From Photo  Album</button><br>
<img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
<img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP Code (upload.php):**

```
<?php
print_r($_FILES);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],   "192.168.3.153/uploads/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
?>
```

Comment: use file transfer plugin

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to get the image as a Base64 encoded string, send that back to the server and then save it into the DB, either in encoded form, or decode it and then save it as a file on the server or a blob in a database.

I don't know the exact implementation procedure as I'm not a Cordova dev, I just sit next to one at work who was tearing his hair out over something similar recently.

Comment: By all means, enlighten us. - Ah, I see your comment above.

Yes, you can write a plugin, but that's not native Cordova. You're assuming all Cordova devs can write plugins.

Comment: no, file transfer plugin is one of the core cordova plugins, you just need javascript to use it. I assume all cordova devs read the documentation and know all the available core plugins. https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer

Answer (score 0):

In cordova we have plugin `file transfer` which is used to download / upload files from server. You have to use this plugin to upload image taken from camera.

Check following [link](http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/07/12/upload-image-using-file-transfer-cordova-plugin-for-ios-and-android/) that details how to upload file to server

Following is a Javascript function that picks a file stored in mobile device and send it to server

```
function uploadfiletoserver(filename){ // where filename is the file store in device
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSys) {
    //The folder is created if doesn't exist
    fileSys.root.getDirectory( 'APP STORAGE FOLDER', {create:true, exclusive: false},
        function(directory) {
            //find the file
            directory.getFile(filename, {create: false, exclusive: false}, 
                function(file){
                    var imageURI = file.toInternalURL();
                    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
                    options.fileKey = "uploadfile";  //this is the value use to refer the file uploaded to server e.g. $_FILES['uploadfile']
                    options.fileName = file.name;

                    var ft = new FileTransfer();
                    ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI('http://www.yourdomain.com/upload.php'), function (r) {
                        console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
                        console.log("Response = " + r.response);
                        console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
                    }, function (error) {
                        console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
                        console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
                    }, options);

                    console.log("upload file: "+imageURI);
                },
                function(error){
                    console.log("Error "+error);
                }
            );
        },
        resOnError);
    },
    resOnError);
}
```

In server PHP file,

```
<?php
    $tmpName = $_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileName = $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];
    $fileDestPath = 'YOUR_UPLOAD_FOLDER_IN_SERVER'.$fileName;
    if($tmpName != 'none') {
        move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $fileDestPath); 
    }
?>
```

Comment: I am able to take a pic and browse gallery pictures with my code added above. but once i take a picture from camera (or) browse pictures from gallery and press the back button on my android 5.0 nexus device , i cannot open the camera (or ) browse pictures again . Did i miss something  ?