# Upload and Save image in phpMyAdmin Xampp server using php api in Flutter

Tags: php, mysql, flutter

This code working fine inserting the row in table but the only problem is that it is not saving the image in any directory. 
I get this solution form this [this stack over link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28086875/save-images-in-xampp-server-from-cordova-with-php)
**Thanks for answering**

**Dart code**

```
  Future startUploadData(File profileImageFile, File coverImageFile) async {

    var uri = Uri.parse(ServerPath.url+"create-shop-profile.php");
    
    var profileStream = http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(profileImageFile.openRead()));
    var profileLength = await profileImageFile.length();

    var coverStream = http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(coverImageFile.openRead()));
    var coverLength = await coverImageFile.length();

    var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);

    /// here passed data eg (request.fields['username'] = username_controller.text;);

    var multipartProfileFile = http.MultipartFile("profileimage", profileStream, profileLength, filename: basename(profileImageFile.path));
    request.files.add(multipartProfileFile);
    var multipartCoverFile = http.MultipartFile("coverimage", coverStream, coverLength, filename: basename(coverImageFile.path));
    request.files.add(multipartCoverFile);

    var respond = await request.send();
    if(respond.statusCode==200) {
      setStatus("Done");
    } else {
      setStatus("Upload Failed"+respond.statusCode.toString());
    }
  }
```

PHP API

```
$profileImagePath = "uploaded_images/profile_image/".$profile_image;
$coverImagePath = "uploaded_images/cover_image/".$cover_image;

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profileimage']['tempname'], $profileImagePath);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['coverimage']['tempname'], $coverImagePath);

$conn->query("INSERT INTO shop_profile (user_id, name, username, profile_image_path, cover_image_path, phone, bio, address, map_link, category, open_time, close_time, sunday, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday) VALUES ('".$user_id."', '".$name."', '".$username."', '".$profileImagePath."', '".$coverImagePath."', '".$phone."', '".$bio."', '".$address."', '".$map_link."', '".$category."', '".$open_time."', '".$close_time."', '".$sunday."', '".$monday."', '".$tuesday."', '".$wednesday."', '".$thursday."', '".$firday."', '".$saturday."')");
```

Comment: _Side note:_ PHPMyAdmin is just a web based management tool for managing MySQL databases. Your application is talking to MySQL directly and has nothing to do with PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: It's `['tmp_name']`, not `['tempname']` Read through https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: If you use direct user input in an SQL statement your code will be open to [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). Always do proper sanitation and most importantly prepared statements when using user input.